# A way to share code between multiple android test modules

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing, android-instrumentation

I want to achieve something like this:

```
[ComponentTestsModule] com.android.test
[FunctionalTestsModule] com.android.test
both depends on
 -> [TestLibraryModule] ?
which depends on
   -> [AppModule] com.android.application
```

Is there any way to do it with android Gradle plugin 3.0+?

### Why I need multiple test modules?

I want different test runners for different types of tests, also target different variants.
It is working right now with single codebase under `androidTest`, but with ugly switches in the custom test runner.

### Why I need a test library module?

I want to share the same page-objects between different types of tests, and maybe some utility code.
Problem is: that page objects must have access to R class of app (locators: R.id.*)

None of the module types I'm aware of can depend on APK-producing module, expect from `com.android.test`, but i cannot depend from `com.android.test` with another `com.android.test`.

Comment: Did you find any solution of this?

Comment: Nope, still no clue

Answer (score 8):

I have recently faced this problem and just want to share my solution in case some body needs it.

What I have done so far (not a perfect solution - I guess, but at least it works).

1. Create a new `module` named **testing_base** or some thing like that
2. In **testing_base** `module` **only** put things related to **testing** (Like the code you want it to be shared between modules) in to normal packages, **NOT in the test packages/folders**.
3. From others module, try to import things from testing_base `module`

> ex: `testImplementation project(":testing_base")`

Hope it can helps someone, happy testing!

Comment: d= (◕‿↼ ) Thanks! Unfortunately, creating a new library is the only way to separate test-code from regular-code.

Comment: when run code from command line i got error ` Project with path ':mylibrary' could not be found in project `

Comment: @MahmoudMabrok you probably setting up the new module in a wrong way.

Comment: this error occured only when i use the module that have `mylibrary` at another module.
like Module 1 have module 2, so when i use Module 1 at module 3 i got that error.

Comment: Let's say you have `module1`, `module2` and `module3`. 
`Module1` has dependency to `module2` and `module3` has dependency to `module1`. So which module has dependency to `mylibrary` ?

Answer (score -4):

> I want different test runners for different types of tests

To run a test class with a specific test runner, use the `@RunWith` annotation.

> also target different variants

To target a specific variant, create your tests in `app/src/androidTestVariantName` for instrumented tests or in `app/src/testVariantName` for unit tests.

Comment: How is this relevant to the question?

Comment: @Rafsanjani How is it not? I explicitly quote the points in the question that I am addressing in this answer.